# SSL certificates briefly appearing on site, then dissapearing

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, https

I'm implementing SSL on my site, but the green bar on Chrome blinks for a moment then disappears. My cert is signed by Comodo. AFAIK my nginx config is right, but I can't seem to get the https to stick.  My 8080 redirect works and my certs have chmod 600, and are in the specified directories.

Any ideas?

```
server {
    listen          8080;
    server_name     *.example.com;
    return          301 https://www.example.com;
}

server {
    listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             *.example.com;
        ssl_certificate         /home/ubuntu/example.com.ssl/example.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/ubuntu/example.com.ssl/example.com.key;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:3333;
    }
}
```

EDIT : My certificate is signed by a trusted authority.

Comment: Are your certs self-signed or are they signed by one of the certificate authorities that the browser trusts by default?

Comment: Signed by Comodo, so an authority.

Comment: have u tried it with another browser by chance?

Comment: I've tried Safari and Chrome.  I see the blinking in Chrome, but Safari doesn't seem to acknowledge the SSL at all.

Comment: Run your site through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: @BazzaDP, thanks, that helped out a lot!  It looks like I'm missing my CA files, or some such.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments https config setup is best tested by running your site through this tool: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

You mention missing some CA files so I'm guessing that your cert is only the cert for your site and not the full chain back to the root cert?

This is easily enough verified by looking at your cert file:

```
ssl_certificate     /home/ubuntu/example.com.ssl/example.com.crt;
```

If this file contains one cert then (only one BEGIN CERTIFICATE line) that is the issue. It should contain at least two certs (for a three cert chain) and possibly more if your CA uses a longer cert chain. The root cert does not need to be (and should not be!) in this file as its already known by the browser.

So get the intermediate certs (they should have been supplied with your cert - but also available [here for Comodo](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/620/0/which-is-root-which-is-intermediate)) and then merge into one file:

```
cat example.com.crt intermediate.crt > example.com_with_chain.crt
```

or if you have two intermediates then as follows (where intermediate1.crt os the cert that issued your cert and it was issued by intermediate2.crt, which was issued by root cert trusted by your browser):

```
cat example.com.crt intermediate1.crt intermediate2.crt > example.com_with_chain.crt
```

Note the order is important. Then update your `ssl_certificate` config to point to these combined crt instead and restart Nginx and repeat the ssltest test.